# Increasing a value with the multiple of 2 other values in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to increase a value 'a' by 'b' * 0.1
How would I do this in MongoDB? I know about '$inc' and '$mul' but I don't know how to combine them.

My try:
`collection.update_many({}, {'$inc': {'a': {'$mul': {'b', 0.1}}}})`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out you can use the aggregation pipeline to do it like this

```
collection.update_many({}, [{"$set": {"a": {"$add": [{"$multiply": ["$b", 0.1]}, "$a"]}}}])
```

This may not be the best way to do it tho